# adding more <ReactSVG> in render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, components

I'm using react-svg in my react sidebar component

```
<NavItem>
  <NavLink href="/position">
    <ReactSVG 
      src="svg/circle-graph.svg" 
      svgClassName="svg-class-name1" 
      className="wrapper-class-name"
    />
    <span className="sidebarlink" >
      {process.env.REACT_APP_POSITION}
    </span>
  </NavLink>
</NavItem>
<NavItem>
  <NavLink href="/operation">
    <ReactSVG src="svg/caveau.svg" />
    <span className="sidebarlink" >Operation</span>
  </NavLink>
</NavItem>
etc...
```

The problem is: I use different svg for each navitem, but I see the same svg! Why this?

Comment: Use the browser developer mode to inspect the results, debug the flow, and force reloads.

Comment: seems to be regular .. the svg path is correct

Comment: Work from the known to the unknown. Are you _sure_ those SVGs are distinct? Are you sure they are being loaded from the path you specify? How do you know? How would you test these assertions? Show your research.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, for example if i delete the first svg, the second svg change, and it's the same for the third ecc.. 

The first <reactsvg> replace all svg with the same svg

Comment: it seems like this component only considers the first element, 
and using it several times  it goes to put the same svg into follow components

Comment: You should show this research so it is part of the text of the question. I see you have asked at the vendor site which is really where the answer will be. Since ReactSVG just injects the SVG into the DOM, you could inspect that closer to verify what is going on.

Comment: But it looks like this API deliberately caches the SVG, and since there is no way to disambiguate multiple ReactSVG items with a _null_ class in the DOM, this is probably caching at work. Maybe see if `svgClassName` can be used to create a non-null class outside of the NavItem that can be referenced inline elsewhere.

Comment: I tried to set a svgClassName="class1--2--3..." for each svg in page but the problem persist.. i tried another component for svg and i have the same problem

Comment: This looks like a bug and you should raise a bug report with the maintainers. Make sure you get a copy of the rendered DOM tree as evidence.

Comment: ok, so, another best way to add more svg in page?

Comment: I've seen React Nav* examples that use icons downloaded from an icon store of some sort. But I think React-SVG is a non-starter.

Comment: The example are all with one svg, i need to use 5 or 6 svg

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html Maybe you could use one of those techniques along with https://stackoverflow.com/q/49736475/1531971 to update the image dynamically from your resources. But I'm out of my depth here. I'd have to hack it just as you will.